# Create a Python function that calculates the average of 3 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, average

I am trying to create a Python function that calculates the average of 3 temperatures. I am a beginner at Python so I wanted to make sure I am on the right track.
This is what I have so far:

```
def average(temp_one, temp_two, temp_three): 
  avg = (int(temp_one) + int(temp_two) + int(temp_three))/3
  return avg
```

Then I have to use the function created that prompts for 3 temperatures and calculates the average. The average output must include one decimal place.

```
def average(temp_one, temp_two, temp_three): 
  avg = (int(temp_one) + int(temp_two) + int(temp_three))/3
  return (avg)

temp_one = float(input(“Enter temperature one:”))
temp_two = float(input(“Enter temperature two:”))
temp_three = float(input(“Enter temperature three:”))
average = ( temp_one+ temp_two + temp_three ) // 3
print (average(temp_one, temp_two, temp_three))
```

For this part I am not very sure of.. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Your calculation is doing unnecessary casts to `int` which loses some precision. In fact, it truncates decimal places, thus lowers your average artificially.

**2.** You are not using the function you have written. Instead you repeat your calculation code with integer division `//`. Note that:

```
5 /  2 == 2.5  # floating point division
5 // 2 == 2    # integer division
```

so here, you are losing information as well.

**3.** You should format your output to one decimal place. This is best done using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

**Thus:**

```
def average(temp_one, temp_two, temp_three): 
  return (temp_one + temp_two + temp_three) / 3  
  # why cast to int and lose precision

# read your 3 float inputs  ...

avg = average(temp_one, temp_two, temp_three)  # actually use your function
print('{:.1f}'.format(avg))  # format output
```

Comment: good solid answer ... to bad you wont be available during the test :P +1

Comment: No? We used to have open internet exams :D maybe not in SD1, though

Comment: So my new code is...
    >def average(temp_one, temp_two, temp_three): 
     >>return (temp_one, temp_two, temp_three) / 3


   >>>avg= average(temp_one, temp_two, temp_three) 
But it gives me an invalid syntax error highlighting the "avg" above.

Comment: Do the three temp variables exist at that point, i.e. have you stored your input in under those names? Have you checked your code indentation, it must be consistent throughtout your file.

Comment: or us `+` instead of `,` in your return ... :P

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"%0.1f"%my_float
#or
"{0:0.1f}".format(my_float)
#or
"{my_float:0.1f}".format(my_float=my_float)
```

will print a float with 1 decimal place see also [python format strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)